# Populate option list from database

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, foreach

In my DB table `row()` I have "24, 26, 28, 30" size in 'product_size' column.

After query, I want to view in viewProduct.php page like:

```
<'option value=" ">' size <'/option>`<br />
<'option value="24"> 24 <'/option>`<br />
<'option value="26"> 26 <'/option>`<br />
<'option value="28"> 28 <'/option>`<br />
<'option value="30"> 30 <'/option><br/>
```

As like as `foreach()` loop.

Comment: It would be good if you provided some code

Comment: and as DB you mean MySQL? Using mysqli?

Comment: `<'option` huh ? why extra single quote ?

Comment: `row()` returns only 1 row, and surely you cannot `foreach()` that the way you intended it to be, use `result()` or `result_array()`

Comment: yes I use MySQL Database. and I model returns only row...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use explode method ;

```php
$array=explode(",",$row['product_size']);
for($i=0;$i<count($array);$i++) {
  echo $array[$i];
  enter code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is what you need:

```
<select name="product[location_id]">
<?php
foreach($product_locations as $product_location) :
    echo "<option value=\"".$product_location['id']."\" ".($product_location['id'] == $product['product_location'] ? "selected=\"yes\"" : "").">".$product_location['title']."</option>";
endforeach;
?>
</select>
```

Of course you need to adapt it to your table/columns since you didn't provide any information about it.